# Start from x date for calendar within form driven by php, jquery and html

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, calendar

We've been tasked with editing a form on a website to start from a particular date in June. It currently starts on today's date. Obviously once the specified date has passed, it will then need to start from the day's date again.

The first part of the jQuery on the current form is below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!--/jQuery UI-->
    <script>
        jQuery(function ($) {
            var dateFormat = "dd/mm/yy";
            $("#check_in").datepicker({dateFormat: dateFormat, minDate: '0d', onSelect: function (dateStr) {
                    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                    if (date) {
                        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
                        var formattedDate = new Date(date);
                        var d = formattedDate.getDate();
                        var m = formattedDate.getMonth();
                        m += 1;
                        var y = formattedDate.getFullYear();
                        var minDate2 = d + "/" + m + "/" + y;
                        $("#check_out").val(d + "/" + m + "/" + y);
                    }
                },
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    var date2 = $('#check_in').datepicker('getDate');
                    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 1);
                    $("#check_out").datepicker("option", "minDate", date2);
                }}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            $("#check_out").datepicker({dateFormat: dateFormat, minDate: '+1d'}).datepicker("setDate", "+1D");
        });
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery(".bookingSubmit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location.href = "https://subdomain.maindomain.com/#/?city=" + jQuery("#city").val() + "&check_in=" + jQuery("#check_in").val() + "&check_out=" + jQuery("#check_out").val() + "&page=1";
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The php segment is below:

```
                                    <div class="form-control">
                                    <!--<label for="city">Check-In:</label>-->
                                    <input type="text" name="check_in" id="check_in" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-control">
                                    <!--<label for="city">Check-Out:</label>-->
                                    <input type="text" name="check_out" id="check_out" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-control">
                                    <!--<label for="city"></label>-->
                                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="bookingSubmit" />
                                </div>
```

The final part of the jQuery script is below:

```
 <script>

        jQuery(function () {

            var opts = {
                defaultDate: "+1w",
                showWeek: true,
                firstDay: 1,
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1,
                dateFormat: "d MM yy",
                altFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                onClose: function (addDays) {
                    var dateArr = jQuery('#start').datepicker('getDate');
                    var dateLeav = jQuery('#end').datepicker('getDate');
                    if (!(dateArr < dateLeav)) {
                        dateArr.setDate(dateArr.getDate() + 2);
                        jQuery('#end').datepicker('setDate', dateArr);
                    }
                    ;
                }
            };

            jQuery('#start').datepicker(
                    jQuery.extend({
                        altField: '#from, .arrivalDate'
                    }, opts)
                    );
            jQuery('#end').datepicker(
                    jQuery.extend({
                        altField: '#to, .leavingDate'
                    }, opts)
                    );
            jQuery('.arrivalDate').datepicker(
                    jQuery.extend({
                        altField: '#start'
                    }, opts)
                    );
            jQuery('.leavingDate').datepicker(
                    jQuery.extend({
                        altField: '#end'
                    }, opts)
                    );

            var queryDate = new Date('06/04/2018');
            var end_date = new Date('06/06/2018');
            var today_date = new Date();

            if (today_date <= queryDate) {
                jQuery("#start").datepicker('setDate', queryDate);
                jQuery("#end").datepicker('setDate', end_date);
            }

            else {
                jQuery("#start").datepicker('setDate', '+0d');
                jQuery("#end").datepicker('setDate', '+2d');
            }

        });

    </script>
```

Any help or pointers greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any PHP here

Comment: It's jQuery really that needs to be edited, any ideas on where to start looking at code entered?